# org.apache.axis2 maven plugin, not picking up the proper wsdlFile

Tags: java, maven, wsdl, apache-axis

Using **org.apache.axis2 maven plugin**, I am trying to generate stubs out of two WSDL files. I have mentioned the wsdl file names in to `<wsdlFile>My/WSDL/File</wsdlFile>`. The plugin is still picking up the default WSDL file name `/src/main/resources/service.wsdl`. Since my wsdlFile names are not service.wsdl, I am getting **java.io.FileNotFoundException**. Please help me to change the wsdlFile name to my required wsdlFile name.

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.9</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>ws1</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>wsdl2code</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                   <databindingName>xmlbeans</databindingName>
                   <wsdlFile>src/main/resources/service1.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                   <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>ws2</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>wsdl2code</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                   <databindingName>xmlbeans</databindingName>
                   <wsdlFile>src/main/resources/service2.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                   <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Did you ever get this solved?